# Empty Coefficients in Logistic regression in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to apply some machine learning algorithms to a dataset in Spark (Java).
When Trying the example of  [Logistic regression in spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multinomial-logistic-regression)
the CoefficientMatrixis is something like this:
 
`3 x 4 CSCMatrix
(1,2) -0.7889290490451877
(0,3) 0.2989598305580243
(1,3) -0.36583869680195286 
Intercept: [0.07898530675801645,-0.14799468898820128,0.06900938223018485]`

If i am not wrong, the
 `(1,2) -0.7889290490451877
(0,3) 0.2989598305580243
(1,3) -0.36583869680195286`  represent "best-fit" model for every class.

Now when I am trying my dataset, which has 4 different classes and 8192 feature, the Coefficients is  
`4 x 8192 CSCMatrix 
Intercept: [1.3629726436521425,0.7373644161565249,-1.0762606057817274,-1.0240764540269398]`

I am not familiar with the Logistic regression algorithm, so I can not understand why the there is no "best-fit"?

my code

```
HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF()
              .setInputCol("listT")
              .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
              .setNumFeatures(8192) ;
Dataset<Row> featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(ReviewRawData);
        featurizedData.show();
        IDF idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features");
        IDFModel idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData);
        Dataset<Row> rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData);
//add the label col based on some conditions
        Dataset<Row> lebeldata = rescaledData.withColumn("label",newCol );
        lebeldata.groupBy("label").count().show();  
Dataset<Row>[] splits = lebeldata.select("label","features").randomSplit(new double[]{0.7, 0.3});
        Dataset<Row> train = splits[0];
        Dataset<Row> test = splits[1];

        LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression()
                .setMaxIter(10)
                .setRegParam(0.3)
                .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
                .setLabelCol("label")
                .setFeaturesCol("features")
                .setFamily("multinomial");

        LogisticRegressionModel lrModel = lr.fit(train);
        System.out.println("Coefficients: \n"
                + lrModel.coefficientMatrix() + " \nIntercept: " + 
         lrModel.interceptVector());
```

My dataset

```
+-----+-----+
|label|count|
+-----+-----+
|  0.0| 6455|
|  1.0| 3360|
|  3.0|  599|
|  2.0|  560|
+-----+-----+
```

And when evaluate the classifier, just the first class was predicted.

```
Class 0.000000 precision = 0.599511
Class 0.000000 recall = 1.000000
Class 0.000000 F1 score = 0.749618
Class 1.000000 precision = 0.000000
Class 1.000000 recall = 0.000000
Class 1.000000 F1 score = 0.000000
Class 2.000000 precision = 0.000000
Class 2.000000 recall = 0.000000
Class 2.000000 F1 score = 0.000000
Class 3.000000 precision = 0.000000
Class 3.000000 recall = 0.000000
Class 3.000000 F1 score = 0.000000
```

By the way, I applied the same dataset with the same above steps to another machine learning algorithms on spark and it works fine!

Comment: Hey Mahmoud did you understand what the coefficient matrix is? This is a logistic regression so i think the weights should simply be in the form of 1xn for n features.Why are there multiple for each class since a single set of weights gives the probability of each class .Also what does best fit for each class mean?

Comment: Check my answer for this question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003293/12232260

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problem with `LogisticRegression` from `spark.ml` in Spark 2.1.1 and removing `.setElasticNetParam(0.8)` worked for me.

Another possiblity is that you have high leverage points (outlier in the range of features) in your dataset which skewed the prediction.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what is that parameter for? And when we deleted it what happened? Thanks again let.

Comment: My guess is `setElasticNetParam(0.8)` will force the logistic regression to find a balance between L1 and L2 penalty, and in most cases the L1 penalization will push the regression coefficients to 0 and break the classifier.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Didn't expect a default param value given in documentation to cause issues.